# Communicate with a terminal using pySerial

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial, serial-communication

I have a terminal which I connect to with serial communication, and I want to read from it and write to it some commands I prepared in advance in a string array

Using pySerial, I need to write a code that will read the lines with a stop condition which is a wait from the console for input from the user, and then write the commands from the array

Just want to clarify, it's like an automatic PuTTY, and no I can't connect to the terminal through ssh, and no I can't bood the machine's terminal since it's not a pc

here is what i tried:

```
import serial

Baud_Rate = 9600
Ser = serial.Serial('COM4', Baud_Rate)

while Ser.isOpen():
    input('Error: Ser is already open, please close it manually. if the port is 
closed, press enter\n')
    try:
        Ser.close()
    except serial.serialutil.PortNotOpenError:
        pass
Ser.open()

Serial_com = [] #a str array with the relevant commands

for i in range(len(Serial_com)):
    ter = Ser.readline()
    while ter != 0xaf:
        #print(str(ter))
        print(str(ter.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r\n')))
        ter = Ser.readline()
    sleep(1)
    if i == 0:
        print('login: root')
        Ser.write(bytes("root", encoding='utf-8'))
    else:
        print('\n\n\n\n\nroot @ Ser: ~  # ' + str(Serial_com[i]))
        Ser.write(bytes(Serial_com[i], encoding='utf8'))
```

I realized that once the serial port is waiting for the python code (or the user) to write commands, that it sends the character 0xaf. It might be a coincidence, but still I wrote that as a stop condition for the reading from the terminal

the code can read from the serial port, but once it needs to write to the serial port it won't proceed

I can't share the rest because it's confedencial for a project

Comment: What code have you tried, and what results did you see?  Can you connect to it with a terminal emulator?  If you're on WIndows, putty can do serial ports.

Comment: updated the post with most of the code that I can share here

Comment: Well, you need to KNOW what the signal is, if there is one.  Have you tried just blasting the first command out without waiting for a "go" signal?  Are you sure the connection is 9600 baud?  That's not very quick these days.  And if `Str.readline()` reads a line at a time, then you need `while ter[-1] != 0xaf:` to wait until it ENDS with that character/